# Configuring HTTP 302 Redirects in Nginx

Tags: nginx, swagger, nginx-config

I have an (spring boot swagger) application deployed on a server. It is accessible on http://vm-name:8081/api/swagger-ui.html. This url gets redirected with http status 302 to another page that has a fixed query parameter. The link for it is http://vm-name:8081/api/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api/docs/swagger-config.

How do I configure it in nginx? I want to expose this application through nginx.

I tried adding the below config but it gives "Whitelabel Error Page. This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback". It seems

What other directives do I need to add other than proxy_pass?

Thanks

```
  location /api { 
     proxy_pass http://vm-name:8081; 
 
     proxy_set_header  Host            $host; 
     proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr; 
     proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
     proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https; 
     proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port 443; 
 
     proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'; 
     proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; 
     proxy_connect_timeout     150; 
     proxy_send_timeout        100; 
     proxy_read_timeout        100; 
 
     proxy_buffer_size         8k; 
     proxy_buffers             4 32k; 
     proxy_busy_buffers_size   64k; 
     proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k; 
  }
```

Comment: Usually you control redirections using the [`proxy_redirect`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive. However its default behavior should do the required `Location` header rewrite without any additional tuning. What exactly is your request to the server and what `Location` header value you got?

Comment: The request url is http://vm-name:8081/api/v1/swagger-ui.html and its location header value is /api/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api/docs/swagger-config. This request is redirected with http status 302. The next request with http://vm-name:8081/api/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api/docs/swagger-config and the location header same as the first one also has http status 302. How should the proxy_redirect look like in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use that :

```
location = /api {
     return 302 $scheme://vm-name:8081/api/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api/docs/swagger-config
}
```

or create an rewrite rule

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie, do I add this return statement at the end of the location {} block? Also do we need = in the location statement or is that a typo?